# Why don't I need to "include_directories" after find_package?

Tags: cmake

Recently, I do my project with `openvino` and write the CMakeLists.txt for  compilation and generating the target , as I do :

```
find_package(InferenceEngine 2.1 QUIET)
```

And from `InferenceEngineConfig.cmake`  , I know follwing variable would be defined :

```
# This will define the following variables:
# InferenceEngine_FOUND - True if the system has the 
# Inference Engine library
# InferenceEngine_INCLUDE_DIRS - Inference Engine include 
  directories
# InferenceEngine_LIBRARIES - Inference Engine libraries
```

After doing `find_package()` , I do :

```
include_directories(${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${InferenceEngine_INCLUDE_DIRS} )
```

And do all the things it needs to getenrate the shared library which is exactly what I need.

However , When I delete this line :
`#include_directories(${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${InferenceEngine_INCLUDE_DIRS} )`

Everthing still works fine which really confuses me...May Somebody tell me the logic behind all of this ? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Probably, the include directory, specified by `${InferenceEngine_INCLUDE_DIRS}`, is already added for **some other reasons**. E.g. it is an include directory for other package which is used in your project. Or it is a system-wide include directory.

Comment: Is there a `target_link_libraries(your_target ... OpenCV)` or something like this? If this is the case and assuming OpenCV does properly attach the include dirs to the imported targets it's simply added, since linking the OpenCV target automatically adds the public(and interface) include dirs to your target. I'd advise you to do the same, i.e. not adding include dirs to a directory, but adding them to targets using `target_include_directories`.

Answer (score 0):

It may be related to the content of files `OpenCVConfig.cmake` and `InferenceEngineConfig.cmake`. I found an annotation in my `OpenCVConfig.cmake` file:

`include_directories(${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS}) # Not needed for CMake >= 2.8.11`

So I think the `include_directories()` has been executed when the `find_package(OpenCV)` is finished.